# ¿validar campo de texto asp.net?

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net

Tengo un campo de texto asp:textbox el el cual debo ingresar de 1 a 2 números enteros desde un teclado creado con button type="button", no he usado asp:button porque este teclado y este textbox estan dentro de un modal de bootstrap, y si usaba un asp:button solo reiniciaba la pagina y me cerraba el modal. Bueno el caso esque necesito validar el textbox para que solo acepte cierta cantidad de números.

Lo intente con las herramientas de validación que ya tiene .net pero no me funciona, no me deja escribir nada en el textbox con los button, así que lo quite y lo intente con jquery, pero solo me limita el espacio cuando escribo con el teclado de mi pc, y si escribo con el teclado que hice no me limita nada.

Espero haberme dado a entender.
Gracias por leer.

```html
<asp:textbox id="sem" runat="server" autocomplete="off"></asp:textbox>
```

```html
<button id="b1" type="button">1</button>
<button id="b2" type="button">2</button>
<button id="b3" type="button">3</button>
<button id="b4" type="button">4</button>
<button id="b5" type="button">5</button>
<button id="b6" type="button" ...etc..
```

```html
//Utilice esta función pero como ya dije, si escribo con el teclado que he 
hecho me deja escribir más de 2 números.

function validar(){
 sem=$('#head_sem').val();
 if (sem.length<2){
  return true;
 }
 else {
  alert('Maximo 2 caracteres');
  return false;
  
 }
```

Comment: Muestra el codigo donde llamas a la funcion validar()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si pudieras mostrar el código sería de más ayuda. Lo que veo es que en tu función validar el id del elemento puede que no corresponda con el id del TextBox. Los webforms tienen su forma particular de generar los IDs.

Puedes probar con esto en tu función para obtener el id real del textbox en HTML:

```
 sem=$('#' + '<%= sem.ClientID %>').val();
 // sem.ClientID hace referencia al id del textbox
```

Tambien puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
 sem=$('[id$=sem]').val();
 // [id$=sem] igualmente sem hace referencia al id declarado en el textbox, básicamente lo que hace ese selector es buscar los elementos que en el id terminen con la palabra sem
```

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/#attributevalue